# Redis Client Side Caching for .Net

Tags: .net, redis, stackexchange.redis, servicestack.redis

Redis 6 has introduced a feature supporting Client Side Caching and is described in here: https://redis.io/topics/client-side-caching

I tried out the ServiceStack.Redis and StackExchange.Redis clients, but couldn't make either of them handle it.

Can anyone help with a working example in C#/.Net? (any client)

Comment: It looks like [there's an open issue on github](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/1461). It didn't look like there was any public info about it being implemented, yet, on that specific thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try the high performance RESP3 supported **TheUniversalCity.RedisClient** library linked below. If you use the client caching mechanism, you'll see about 30x faster than Stackexchange.Redis. Even if you don't use the client caching mechanism, it's already at least twice as fast as Stackexchange.Redis.

This library support;

- RESP3 protocol and also client side caching.
- High speed auto pipelining algorithim

https://github.com/TheUniversalCity/RedisClient

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem either of them support it yet.

If you mean ANY clients,version 6.0.0.RC1 redis client [Lettuce](https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core/releases) for Java languages supports it now.

It's the most popular redis-client on the most used language, and its support for Redis 6.0 is only added a few days ago.

So it's not surprising to find that most other clients have not implemented it yet.

Comment: I've updated the question as I need support for .Net, but I do appreciate the answer.